# how to create a background thread when an exception is thrown by activeMq that will work on a class level vector?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a publisher for a topic in activeMq that in case of an exception pushes the `TextMessage` to a vector. I want to spawn a thread when the exception occurs and this thread should keep retrying to push the messages to the same topic. But there should only be one thread and not multiple threads in case of an exception.

```
private Vector<TextMessage> pendingQueue = new Vector<TextMessage>(); 

@Override
public void sendMessage(Object myMessage)
{ 
    try 
    {
        factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(activeMQServerURL);
        connection = factory.createConnection();
        connection.start();
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        destination = session.createTopic(cmdTopicName);
        producer = session.createProducer(destination);
        message = session.createTextMessage();
        message.setText(new Gson().toJson(myMessage));
        producer.send(message);          
    }
    catch (JMSException  e)
    {
        pendingQueue.add(message);
        runBackgroundDLQJobs();
    }            
}
public void runBackgroundDLQJobs()
{
    bgThread.start();
}
```

And Run method of bgThread:

```
@Override
public void run()
{
    while (pendingQueue.size() > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            int idx = 0;

            while (idx < pendingQueue.size())
            {
                boolean sendDLQMessagesSuccess = sendDLQMessages(pendingQueue.get(idx));
                if (sendDLQMessagesSuccess)
                {
                    pendingQueue.remove(idx);
                    idx++;
                }
                else
                {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        //DoSomething
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Vector?? Which version of Java are you on?

Comment: @GergelyBacso jdk1.7